# In many lines of the same values that I want to be counted

Tags: shell

main faile is:

785 
785 
788 
788 
883 
883 
883 
921 
921 
921 
921 
921 
921 
925 
925

I want to count the same values and write the results in a new file (as follows):
785 2
788 2
883 3
921 6
925 2

Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine your file is called t

You can do with:

```
cat t | sort -u | while read line #read each one element in sorted and uniqye
do
   echo -n $line; # print element
   cat t | grep ${line} | wc -l # read file, get only the specified and count
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sort myFile.txt | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2 " " $1}' > myNewFile.txt
```

Edit: added `sort` and removed `cat` to take comments into account

And if you want only values which appear at least 4 times:

```
sort temp.txt | uniq -c | sort -n | egrep -v "^ *[0-3] "  | awk '{ print $2 " " $1}'
```

Comment: also, if the count is >=4 , can we add it to the upper command? && thank you..

Comment: What count are you talking about?

Comment: `uniq` requires the file has already been sorted. but OP didn't mention that. also, what is the `cat` command for?

Answer (score 0):

```
kent$  awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)print x, a[x]}' f
921  6
925  2
883  3
785  2
788  2
```

print only `count >=4`:

```
kent$  awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(x in a)if(a[x]>=4)print x, a[x]}' f    
921  6
```